# Process.Start() of a console app not working from Windows Service in Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application, windows-server-2008-r2, process.start

**Update (3/20/2014 5:11PM EST):** have added code to write "GotHere0.txt".  Gothere0, 1, 2, 3 all appear fine.  Gothere4 does not appear.

Please note - this is not a duplicate - it has very subtle differences with all existing threads I have found.

Requirements:

1. Launch a console application from a Windows Service, that is running under the Local System account, in Windows Server 2008 R2
2. The code inside of the console application writes to a SQL database, and writes files to a drive, but does not require user input (and there is no requirement to see or interact with the Console itself).  All we need is the code from the console application to execute.
3. This should work when the server is started, without requiring a user to login.

Results so far:

Process.Start(sInfo) completes as if everything was successful.  No exceptions are thrown.  A Process ID > 0 is returned.  However, it is clear that no code within testapp.exe actually executes.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\GotHere0.txt", "");
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Run(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            ContinueRunning = false;
        }

        public static bool ContinueRunning = true;
        public void Run()
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\GotHere1.txt", "");
            while (ContinueRunning)
            {
                try
                {
                    List<string> args = new List<string>();
                    args.Add("Test");
                    StartApp(@"c:\temp\testapp.exe", args);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }

                if (ExitEarly()) return;
            }
        }

        private static void StartApp(string exePath, List<string> args)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\GotHere2.txt", "");
                ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                sInfo.FileName = exePath;
                sInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
                sInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", args);
                sInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                Process runningProcess = Process.Start(sInfo);

                string message = "";
                if (runningProcess!=null)
                {
                    message = runningProcess.Id.ToString();
                }
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\GotHere3.txt", message);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\GotHere4.txt", exc.Message);
            }
        }
        private static bool ExitEarly()
        {
            // Sleep for a total of 60 seconds, and return if "OnStop" is called.
            for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (!ContinueRunning) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for testapp.exe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("NO arguments were passed.");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string arg in args)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("Arg: [" + arg + "]");
                }
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("helloworld.txt", sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried starting the service with *normal* (not a default services) user account, e.g. yours and then see if it works?

Comment: How is it clear no code actually executed? How are you verifying that the program did not run?

Comment: All the console app does is write a text file "helloworld.txt" to the same folder.  Have also tried writing it to c:\temp.  Both don't work.  Note: all of this works fine on my Windows 8 box.  I'm starting to suspect it's a Group Policy setting on the Windows Server 2008 R2 box.  Is anyone aware of a Group Policy that could affect this?

Comment: Which user are you running the service under?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lasse.  The service is running under "Local System"

Answer (score -1):

If you are expecting to see a UI from the application you are launching, you wont. You can't launch a UI from a service.

Comment: Not expecting a UI.  Just looking for code to run inside the console app.